# C Remove substring between two characters

Tags: c, string, substring

I have two possible strings that would be pointed to by a char *:

```
char *s = "this is a string";
char *s = "this is a string [this is more string]";
```

I want to be able to remove the brackets and their contents from the char if they exist. What is the best way to do that in C?

Thanks!

Comment: Steps:  1. create editable buffer equal in `size` to the source string.  2) use `memcpy` to copy the target region of the source string into the editable buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you must have access to memory you are permitted to modify. For hysterical raisins, C still allows you to declare pointers to constant character arrays as non-const... but you still can’t modify them.

Instead, declare yourself an array which is initialized by the constant data.

```
char s[] = "hello world";
```

That gives you a mutable array of 11+1 characters (a *copy* of the immutable source string).

Often, however, we want to be able to work on our strings, so we need to make sure there is enough room to play with them.

```
char s[100] = "hello world";  // string capacity == 99+1. In use == 11+1.
s[6] = '\0';              // now string contains "hello ". In use == 6+1.
strcat( s, "everyone" );  // now string contains "hello everyone". In use == 14+1.
```

To *remove* content from a string, you must first identify where the start and stop is:

```
char s[] = "this is a string [this is more string] original string";
char * first = strchr( s, '[' );  // find the '['
char * last  = strchr( s, ']' );  // find the ']'
if (first and last)  // if both were found...
  // ...copy the end of the string over the part to be replaced
  memmove( first, last+1, strlen(last+1)+1 );
// s now contains "this is a string  original string"
```

Notice all those `+1`s in there? Be mindful:

- of *where* you are indexing the string (you want to copy from *after* the `']'` to the end of the string)
- that strings must end with a nul-terminator — a zero-valued character (which we should also copy, so we added one to the strlen).

Remember, a **string** is just an array of characters, where the last *used* character is immediately followed by a zero-value character (the nul-terminator). All the methods you use to handle arrays of any other kind apply to handling strings (AKA arrays of characters).

Comment: Like seeing `memmove()` being used... UV... Now to address _nested_ regions... `:-)`

Comment: LOL, yeah, I thought about that but my answer is already overload for a newbie... Just wait until he/she gets the assignment to check for balanced parentheses or verify strings for a C source code or something...

Comment: `if (first and last)` is not sufficient, `last` must also be greater than `first` to avoid undefined behavior on `char *s = "Hello ] world [ \n");`

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those "fun" problems that attracts more than its share of answers.

Full credit to other answers for noting that attempts to modify a "string literal" triggers UB. (String literals are often stored in an *immutable* "read only" region of memory.) (Thanks to @chux-reinstatemonica for clarification.)

Taking this to the next level, below is a bit of code that handles both multiple regions bounded by a pair of delimiters ('[' & ']'), and handles *nested* instances, too. The code is simple enough, using `cut` as a counter that ensures nesting is accounted for. NB: It is presumed that the source string is "well formed".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char *wb =
         "Once [upon] a [time] there [lived a] princess. "
         "She [ was [a hottie]]. The end.";
    char wo[100]; // big enough

    int cut = 0;
    size_t s = 0, d = 0; 

    for( ; wb[s]; s++ ) {
        cut += ( wb[s] == '[' ); // entering region to cut?
        if( !cut ) wo[ d++ ] = wb[ s ]; // not cutting, so copy
        cut -= ( wb[s] == ']' ); // exiting region that was cut?
        if( cut < 0 ) cut = 0; // in case of spurious ']'
    }
    wo[ d ] = '\0'; // terminate shortened string

    puts( wb );
    puts( wo );

    return 0;
}
```

```
Once [upon] a [time] there [lived a] princess. She [ was [a hottie]]. The end.
Once  a  there  princess. She . The end.
```

It now becomes a small challenge to, perhaps, remove multiple consecutive SPs in the output array. This could quite easily be done *on the fly*, and is left as an exercise.

One begins to see how something like this could be extended to make an "infix calculator program". Always something new!

Comment: It fails with unbalanced parentheses `"She [ was [a hottie]. The end." ` you've been too bold :)

Comment: One look at this and I see a mad-lib-esqe program challenge coming up. String replace `"Once upon a time there lived a [Noun]. She was [Adjective]."`

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't pay atentino to the _It is presumed that the source string is "well formed"_ part

Comment: @DavidRanieri Bold? Not at my age! :) There is a disclaimer that the source string being "well formed" is assumed...

Comment: Yes, I just commented it :) UV

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strchnul` function defined in `string.h`

```c
    *(strchrnul(s, '[')) = '\0';
```

You may need to define the `_GNU_SOURCE` macro.
It won't work on string literals.

Comment: Have you tested it with a string literal?

Comment: No. Strings literals aren't modifiable so you'll need to make a copy if you wanna modify one.

Comment: Then put it in the answer :) Anyway OP wants to remove a substring (you are cutting from the substring)

Comment: Ah . Sorry for that. On the original example question both were equivalent.

Comment: I did the same error :) yeah, OP is using a bad example

Comment: Alas, `strchrnul()` doesn’t exist on Windows/MSVC.

Comment: @glk0 `strchnul()` in not part of the standard C library.  This answer relies on a library extension.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the bracketed fragment(s) from the string, you cannot modify the string literal in place. You should either use an automatic array or an allocated block and construct the modified string there.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strip_brackets(const char *s) {
    size_t i, j, len;
    char *p;

    // compute the modified string length
    for (i = len = 0; s[i];) {
        if (s[i] == '[') {
            for (j = i + 1; s[j] && s[j] != ']'; j++)
                continue;
            if (s[j] == ']') {
                i = j + 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        len++;
        i++;
    }
    p = malloc(len + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // construct the modified string
        for (i = len = 0; s[i];) {
            if (s[i] == '[') {
                for (j = i + 1; s[j] && s[j] != ']'; j++)
                    continue;
                if (s[j] == ']') {
                    i = j + 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            p[len++] = s[i++];
        }
        p[len] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}

int main() {
    const char *s = "this is a string [this is more string]";
    char *s1 = strip_brackets(s);
    printf("before: %s\n", s);
    if (s1) {
        printf("after : %s\n", s1);
        free(s1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```